# Auto-synch browser tabs on two PCs?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, firefox-extensions, google-chrome-extensions

How can I have the same browser open on two different PCs and always have the same tabs open on both, no matter which one I change?

Any browser. I don't care so long as I get the desried functionality.

Comment: Which browser? All or just one? With Google Chrome you need to close on machine A and then open on machine B to see the changes.

Comment: +1 Any browser. I don't care so long as I get teh desried functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox and Chrome have the ability to sync opened tabs via their own browser-dependent sync-servers. But it won't work with two browsers opened at the same time.

Comment: +1 and thanks, but it looks lika I am still searching :-(

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you want live-tab-sync across multiple browsers. I can't really think od use-case for this.

Comment: Those only seem to show the tabs open on the other instance not close / open them? (My use case is a dual boot desktop and a laptop - I want to be able to continue if I switch OSes or move to my laptop....)

Answer (score 2):

With Firefox you probably want to enable Firefox Sync: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/what-firefox-sync

Comment: +1, buyt what about @user1039462's statement that "it won't work with two browsers opened at the same time"?

Comment: I think what he was thinking about: Having i.e. both Chrome and Firefox open on the same computer and let them have the same tabs open all the time. Obviously not what you asked for :)